# Can Anyone told me how to remove dark Grey bottom side border in CarbonKit

Tags: ios, swift4, uisegmentedcontrol, carbonkit

This is my code for add Carbon kit in my view.

```
    let arrMenuName = ["Signal","Buy or Not"]
    carbonSwipe.delegate = self
    carbonSwipe = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: arrMenuName as [AnyObject], delegate: self)
    carbonSwipe.carbonTabSwipeScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    carbonSwipe.insert(intoRootViewController: self, andTargetView: mainvw)
    carbonSwipe.carbonSegmentedControl?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
    carbonSwipe.carbonSegmentedControl?.setWidth(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2, forSegmentAt: 0)
    carbonSwipe.carbonSegmentedControl?.setWidth(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2, forSegmentAt: 1)
    carbonSwipe.setTabBarHeight(48)
    carbonSwipe.setNormalColor(UIColor.black, font: UIFont.init(name: "SanFranciscoDisplay-Regular", size: 15)!)
    carbonSwipe.setSelectedColor(UIColor.red, font: UIFont.init(name: "SanFranciscoDisplay-Bold", size: 15)!)

    carbonSwipe.setIndicatorHeight(2)
    carbonSwipe.setIndicatorColor(UIColor.red)
```

[image]

Any suggestion could be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: @Kuldeep Thank you its work.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nx6ghgl3kpfsns/ServiceCall.swift?dl=0 Webservice call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by writing below line.

```
carbonSwipe.toolbar.clipsToBounds = true
```